OpenAI API: Cannot assign to property 'search' which has only a getter
I am using an OpenAI Assistant with my own contextual data to get contextual responses to my queries:
const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: xxx });

async function queryNoFileSearch(prompt: string): Promise<string> {
    const assistant = await openai.beta.assistants.create({
        name: "name",
        instructions: "contextual instructions",
        tools: [{ type: "code_interpreter" }],
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo'
    });

    const thread = await openai.beta.threads.create();
    await openai.beta.threads.messages.create(
        thread.id,
        {
            role: 'user',
            content: prompt
        }
    );
    let run = await openai.beta.threads.runs.createAndPoll(
        thread.id,
        {
            assistant_id: assistant.id,
            instructions: "contextual instructions",
        }
    );
    let res = '';
    if (run.status === 'completed') {
        const messages = await openai.beta.threads.messages.list(
          run.thread_id
        );
        for (const message of messages.data.reverse()) {
            const x = message.content[0] as any;
            res += x.text.value + '\n';
        }
    } else {
        res = run.status;
    }
    return res;
}

(async () => {
    const result = await queryNoFileSearch("What bowls do you have available?");
    console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
})();

export default queryNoFileSearch;

When I run this file (in isolation) with ts-node file.ts, I get the result returned as expected. It is a string containing the response from OpenAI. This is great.
However, I am unable to display this text in a React Native component and display it on a screen. The error I am getting is:
Error: Cannot assign to property 'search' which has only a getter
Here is my React Native component so far.
const PredictorScreen = () => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState<string>('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const handlePredict = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const result = await queryNoFileSearch("User makes query here");
      setOutput(result);
    } catch (err) {
      setError('Error: ' + (err as Error).message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="xxx" onPress={handlePredict} />
      <ScrollView style={styles.outputContainer}>
        {loading ? (
          <Text style={styles.outputText}>Loading...</Text>
        ) : error ? (
          <Text style={styles.outputText}>{error}</Text>
        ) : (
          <Text style={styles.outputText}>{output}</Text>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

How can I get the result of queryNoFileSearch to be displayed in a React Native component? It is getting returned and logged to the console just fine when I run the function in isolation in its own file, but I am always facing this Cannot assign to property 'search' which has only a getter error when I try to display the result in a React Native component and I don't know why. Nothing I have found online has fixed my issue.

OpenAI doesn’t offer a dedicated SDK for React Native. To integrate OpenAI’s API within your React Native and Expo projects, you should use direct HTTP requests. Personally I use firebase cloud functions.
